# Easiest way to program an Optimus/Hybrid switch in C++ application

Tags: c++, opengl

I am a contributor to an OpenGL project, and personally use a notebook that has NVidia Optimus.

One cool feature I thought of was to allow the notebook to be able to select between its Intel and NVidia adapter through a console variable that will be available later on to users through a menu option. The way I thought of doing this was through using the SHIM_MCCOMPAT environment variable - and by default, it would leave such a variable untouched, but if a user wanted the application would set it in advance of the OpenGL initialization.

This project really is not heavy on the GPU unless you enable its advanced features, which is why I thought such a switch would be viable in this application - and another side effect would be to eliminate the screen tearing that DWM.exe loves to do on Windows 10 when you enable the NVidia GPU (just switch it to Intel automatically - problem solved!)

So - my question is - can this be done with ATI Hybrid Switchable Graphics, as well? I'd like this capability to exist in ATI notebooks as well, not just my own.

Comment: Hard to tell, which part you need help with: Selecting the render device or passing configuration settings to your application.

Comment: What I really want is to select the render device. Example: cvar "vid_hybrid" is 1 - it will select the NVidia/ATI discrete GPU for such notebooks. "vid_hybrid" being 2, it will select the integrated GPU (often Intel, but sometimes can be a lower-end ATI). vid_hybrid 0 would just leave well enough alone and let the drivers decide based on their operating environment and outside user preferences.

I would prefer a method that isn't API-intensive, like setting an environment variable, but doing simple API queries before the actual OpenGL initialization will also work.

Comment: Every C++ application allows you to pass command line arguments. Still unclear, what you are really having difficulty with. Passing command line arguments to an application is a solved problem.

Comment: That's not what I want. What I want is an ATI equivalent for NVidia's "SHIM_MCCOMPAT" which allows to switch between Optimus's integrated or dedicated GPU's - nothing more. I can implement the configuration myself - I just need to know how to activate ATI's features for this.

Comment: Build in [`NvOptimusEnablement`](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/technologies/desktop/optimus.htm) and/or `AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance` and hope the driver obeys the value instead of just looking for the symbol export.

Comment: This is definitely useful info for other projects, but unfortunately not for the one I am working on. This does not allow the user to configure from inside the application which GPU processor they would prefer to use. Actually - what I want may not be available, from the looks of it, even looking on AMD's site.